# Problem with Cuda-5.0 under Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, cuda

I'm trying to install `cuds-5.0` on Ubuntu 12.10 server, but I am getting some errors. When I try to make the `Makefile` in sample code it told me:

```
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_35'
```

Command and output is as following.

```
u@pc:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Apr__5_00:24:31_PDT_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.2, V0.2.1221
```

Output of `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`:

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.54  Sat Sep 29 00:05:49 PDT 2012
GCC version:  gcc version 4.4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-2ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line is showing that, even though you're invoking `nvcc` from the CUDA 5.0 directory, you end up starting the CUDA 4.2 compilation tools. This version does not support compiling for compute capability 3.5.

So, your primary issue is that you are not invoking the correct compiler. Also, do you have a device of compute capability 3.5? That would be a device based on the new GK110 chip. I think the only card available right now is the Tesla K20.

If you don't have a K20 card, you'll have to compile for a lower compute capability. That is, alter `compute_35` to, for instance, `compute_20`, for a Fermi based card. This is regardless of which compiler you end up using.

Comment: Well, thank you so much and I solved the question.